# How to force librosa to use ffmpeg instead of gstreamer

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, librosa

The code below produces a clean spectrogram when I run it in Windows, but a very rough one in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04). I suspect the difference has to do with the audioread backends. When I run audioread.available_backends() on Linux it reports gstreamer ahead of ffmpeg, but I don't have gstreamer on Windows. Is that really the issue? If so, is there a way to force it to use ffmpeg instead of gstreamer?

```
import argparse
import librosa
import scipy

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('tkagg')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', type=str, default='', help='Path to input file.')
args = parser.parse_args()

signal, rate = librosa.load(args.i, sr=44100, mono=True, res_type='kaiser_fast')

start_seconds = 5.0
end_seconds = 8.0
start_offset = int(start_seconds * rate)
end_offset = int(end_seconds * rate)

f, t, spec = scipy.signal.spectrogram(signal[start_offset:end_offset], fs=rate, mode='magnitude')
                                      
plt.pcolormesh(spec, shading='gouraud')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: I don't think so. `librosa` does not use that backend to calculate spectogram, but relies on `numpy` and `scipy`. What do you mean by "clean" and "rough" spectogram? Is it about graphics or numerical values? If the former, I'd rather focus on plotting libraries and what defaults are in these backends. If the latter, check the versions of `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: I think librosa calls audioread to load the data if it’s an mp3. The spectrogram on Linux is just less smooth - kind of jagged and noisy. Probably the thing to do is skip librosa and call ffmpeg directly https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md#convert-sound-to-raw-pcm-audio.

Answer (score 0):

Using ffmpeg instead of librosa solved the issue in this case, so the problem was what I thought it was. I replaced the librosa.load call above with the following:

```
def buf_to_float(x, *, n_bytes=2, dtype=np.float32):
    scale = 1.0 / float(1 << ((8 * n_bytes) - 1))
    fmt = "<i{:d}".format(n_bytes)
    return scale * np.frombuffer(x, fmt).astype(dtype)

rate = 44100
bytes, _ = (ffmpeg
    .input(args.i)
    .output('-', format='s16le', acodec='pcm_s16le', ac=1, ar=f'{rate}')
    .overwrite_output()
    .run(capture_stdout=True))

signal = np.asarray(buf_to_float(bytes))
```